# Create a row per 15 minute interval between two dates in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I have a table that contains a column with datetime data type. I would like to write a MySQL query which populates the table with a row for each 15 minute interval between two dates (e.g. 2017-01-01 00:00:00 and 2017-06-30 23:45:00).

The purpose of this table is to be able to store a number for each interval like this:

Time interval | Forecast
2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 528
2017-01-01 00:15:00 | 492
2017-01-01 00:30:00 | 474
2017-01-01 00:45:00 | 482
2017-01-01 01:00:00 | 456
2017-01-01 01:15:00 | 421
2017-01-01 01:30:00 | 375
2017-01-01 01:45:00 | 322

What would be the easiest way of achieving this?

Also, there will be some intervals with no forecast (probably about 30% of them will be 0), should I avoid creating that row at all and at a later point write a query that returns 0 if the interval does not exist in the table?

Comment: What do the numbers represent?

Comment: A forecast of a number of interactions per 15 minutes. I just chose some random values on the right column.

Comment: How often do you want to insert records in your table? Do you want to do it once every day and create all 96 records for that day at once? And does the `forecast number` generates automatically and updater the corresponding record itself?

Comment: Also, you only want to do it with `MySQL` or you have access to `php` or something else? If only MySQL I'm afraid you can not do it with only ` query, I think you should use a `procedure`

Comment: I'd be inserting records into the table on a daily base at first, but somewhere along the line I might want to do that every hour. I'd be creating the empty records (rows) about once a month and later update them with a value in the forecast column. I want to create the rows directly in a MySQL query if possible (without PHP).